# What does "error_description:access_denied" mean in BoxServerException

Tags: box-api

I ma trying to refresh my access token using the refresh token I have but I get following exception:

> com.box.boxjavalibv2.exceptions.BoxServerException:
>   {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Access denied"}

Please tell me what could be wrong with my request and why I am getting `access_denied`

If I send invalid refresh token, then I get

> Caused by: com.box.boxjavalibv2.exceptions.BoxServerException:
>   {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid refresh token"}

I want to know the reasons for access_denied.

------------------- relevant code ------------------

```
BoxOAuthRequestObject requestObject = BoxOAuthRequestObject.refreshOAuthRequestObject(refreshToken, clientId,
        clientSecret);
try {
    // Authenticate with the new token
    BoxOAuthToken boxOAuthToken = client.getOAuthManager().refreshOAuth(requestObject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received that error when attempting to call API methods that accessed the "Manage an enterprise" methods, while my application was defined as "Read and write all files and folders".

Make sure you set the appropriate checkbox at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what's going on without more information of your code.

One thing is that the sdk does auto-refresh the OAuth token. So basically you don't need to refresh it yourself. Please check https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2#authenticate